# how to enable drm in rpi 4 to run discovery plus

Tags: raspberrypi, browser

So I would like to run discovery plus in a browser (aura browser<falkon<Firefox<Chromium)
I am on Ubuntu 21.10 arm64 rpi 4 2g ram.
I tried Firefox snap, Firefox deb, falkon, aura browser, chromium snap(browser does not start), and chromium flatpak
in firefox there is no option to enable drm you can test by installing ubuntu rpi4 64 bit and going to the settings of firefox and looking up drm.

Comment: A lot of browser based DRM requires the Google WideVine plugin. Is it installed?

Comment: Can't install it on Firefox no option to do that, but I am compiling Firefox now so that can be tested

Comment: Why can't you install it on Firefox? It's an available plugin. To troubleshoot this we need more details.

Comment: No enable DRM check box